# Unable to Edit CDB file manually

Tags: cdb

I need to edit a CDB file manually using something like text editor, is there a way where I can edit it manually or view its content in a readable way?

I already tried several software available like Noki but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

cdbdump will dump the contents of a cdb into a readable format, which you can then edit and feed back into cdbmake.

https://cr.yp.to/cdb/cdbmake.html